# Find non existing time intervall when doing join to another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, between

I have a question that I dont know If there is solution to in sql.  Made an small example

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Event] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Logging]    Script Date: 2020-07-07 14:35:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logging](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FromTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ToTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Events] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Id], [EventTime], [Event]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2020-07-07T14:14:00.000' AS DateTime), N'str')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Id], [EventTime], [Event]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2020-07-07T07:01:00.000' AS DateTime), N'testcall')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Events] ([Id], [EventTime], [Event]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2020-07-07T15:22:00.000' AS DateTime), N'ipfail')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Events] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Logging] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Logging] ([Id], [FromTime], [ToTime], [Status]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2020-07-07T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-07-07T13:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'All well')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Logging] ([Id], [FromTime], [ToTime], [Status]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2020-07-07T13:01:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-07-07T15:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'All well')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Logging] ([Id], [FromTime], [ToTime], [Status]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2020-07-07T15:33:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-07-07T20:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'All well')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Logging] ([Id], [FromTime], [ToTime], [Status]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2020-07-07T20:01:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2020-07-07T23:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'All well')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Logging] OFF
GO
```

When doing an inner join of this table I want to find the Event in Event table that doesn't have a matching timeframe in Logging. The timeframe that's missing is 15:00 to 15:33 and the event that happens that happens is the Event with ID 3. Everything is measured in minutes. Is this possible? Or have to do it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `not exists`:

```
select l.*
from logging l
where not exists (select 1
                  from events e
                  where e.eventtime >= l.fromtime and
                        e.eventtime <= l.totime
                 );
```

However, this returns two timeframes -- ones with ids 3 and 4.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83f3260416eeef830d2182459bea5505) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think I didnt explain enough. Its the events that doesnt have a coresponding timeframe in logs that should be viewed aka this should give back event with id3